# skydrive app on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, onedrive

We are trying to access skydrive using phonegap.We used an activity to call login function of skydrive. But it does not call login function at all.

Would be great help if someone shed light on this.

Here is the code.

**Here activity is called from plugin class of phonegap**

```
Intent i = new Intent(myac, DispAct.class);
try{
                    System.out.println("before start activity");
                     //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ( this.cordova.getActivity()).startActivity(i);
}
catch(Exception e){  System.out.println("in catch"+e);}
```

**Below code is the called activity**

```
package org.apache.cordova;

import java.util.Arrays;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthException;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthListener;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectClient;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveConnectSession;
import com.microsoft.live.LiveStatus;
import com.microsoft.live.R;

public class DispAct extends Activity
{
    log obj;

    private Object cordova;

     private static final String APP_CLIENT_ID ="00000000400D893E" ;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            System.out.println("disp on create");
     }


        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            System.out.println("disp on start");

            obj=new log();
            obj.auth = new LiveAuthClient(this.getApplicationContext(), APP_CLIENT_ID);
            Iterable<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("wl.basic","wl.signin","wl.skydrive","wl.skydrive_update");
            obj.auth.login(this,scopes,obj);//********this is the function which has to call login page but does not work
            System.out.println("disp after login");

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume()
        {

            super.onResume();
            //finish();
        }
}


final class log implements LiveAuthListener{   

    String type,message;
    LiveConnectClient client;
    LiveAuthClient auth;
    //Parcel out;

    public log()
    {
        //auth=new LiveAuthClient(this, message);
    }

    synchronized public void onAuthComplete(LiveStatus status, LiveConnectSession session, Object userState) {
        if(status == LiveStatus.CONNECTED) {
           // this.resultTextView.setText("Signed in.");
            System.out.println("IN SUCCess");
            client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
            //download(0);
            notify();

        }
        else {
            //this.resultTextView.setText("Not signed in.");
            type="ERROR";
            message="Not Connected";
            client = null;
            System.out.println("IN complete err");
            notify();
        }        
    }



    synchronized public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException exception, Object userState) {
        //this.resultTextView.setText("Error signing in: " + exception.getMessage());        
        client = null;
        //type="ERROR";
        //message="Error logging in";
        System.out.println("IN error");
        notify();
    }
}
```

Here activity is displayed but login page does not appear which should appear as the result of login function